# How to compare access code for Multifactor Signor Authentication

Tags: docusignapi, docusign-sdk

In Quick start java application i am testing "Multi factor Signer Authentication". In my docusign account settings i set the access code should be in min. of 6 characters and 1 upper case letter.
But from a quick start, it accepts any access code with that rule. How can i first send the unique access code and then compare with the signer who is signing the document.

Answer (score 0):

DocuSign does that for you, you don't need to do anything. The access code you provide should be somehow provided to the signer. Ideally not in the same manner (since if email was compromised and you send it over email - that defeats the purpose).
Then, the signer is asked to enter the code and DocuSign compares it to the one that was set. You do not need to do anything in your code.

Comment: Thanks, but where will i set the access code at the first place. There is no provision inside the settings of my docusign developer account (may be am missing it). All i can see is to set the access code rule whether it shd. have numbers or spl. chracters and the max length that is all. Say for User 1 am setting a random unique access code called "us12US" and for User 2 it shd. be "ch23ch". Where will i set those 2 access code?

Comment: Did you write any code to send an envelope?

Comment: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/require-access-code-recipient/

Comment: 9             Signer signer1 = new Signer()
40             {
41                 Name = signerName,
42                 Email = signerEmail,
43                 RoutingOrder = "1",
44                 Status = "Created",
45                 DeliveryMethod = "Email",
46                 RecipientId = "1", // Represents your {RECIPIENT_ID}
47                 AccessCode = accessCode, // Represents your {ACCESS_CODE}
48                 Tabs = signer1Tabs
49             };